# Python + Cassandra CqlPagingInputFormat + Hadoop Streaming

Tags: python, hadoop, cassandra, hadoop-streaming

**Intro**

I have a cassandra 1.2.19 cluster with hadoop 1.2.1 installed and configured in fully distributed mode on top of it (plus an extra non-cassandra node as a master), everything works fine and I can run map-reduce jobs on it.

**The problem**

Now I want to use hadoop streaming to run a map/reduce using python mappers and reducers. The code for the mapper is rather simple it reads each line from standard input, does the "map" and produces some output for the reducer.

I'm running the map/reduce using a command like this from the master:

```
hadoop jar /usr/share/hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-1.2.1.jar \
-D cassandra.input.keyspace="keyspace_name" \
-D cassandra.input.partitioner.class="Murmur3Partitioner" \
-D cassandra.input.columnfamily="cf_name" \
-D cassandra.consistencylevel.read="ONE" \
-D cassandra.input.widerows=true \
-D cassandra.input.thrift.address=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX \
-inputformat org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlPagingInputFormat \
-input /keyspace_name/cf_name \
-output /dev/test \
-file mapper.py  -mapper mapper.py \
-file reducer.py -reducer reducer.py
```

Sample code for mapper.py as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

# input comes from STDIN (standard input)

for line in sys.stdin:
    try:
        # remove leading and trailing whitespace
        line = line.strip()
        # IMPORTANT NOTE: since our tables are key value stores
        #   we are expecting only 2 columns on the input record
        key, value = line.split('\t')
        # do something with the input
```

Since the table I'm using contains only 2 columns (it is a key-value store) I expect hadoop streaming to send key-value pairs with a separator (it defaults to tab I think) but instead the mapper is receiving this:

```
{primary_key=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=97 lim=119 cap=1158]}  {value=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=139 lim=941 cap=1158]}
{primary_key=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=97 lim=119 cap=768]}   {value=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=139 lim=551 cap=768]}
```

It is giving me references to HeapByteBuffers instead of the actual values.

**The questions**

1-Is there a missing parameter when I execute the map/reduce to tell cassandra/hadoop to give me actual value as an input to my mapper instead of this HeapByteBuffer?
2-Is there a way to access the actual value of this HeapByBuffers from python?
3-Is there a better/different way of running hadoop on top of cassandra using mapper/reducers written in python?

Thanks in advance!